# How to use swipe for adding to favorites in checkbox in FastAdaper Android?

Tags: android, fastadapter

I want my RecyclerView Item swipe left and there must be shown star-styled checkBox to add to favorites list. I am using FastAdapter by Mike Penz. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The following question is not related to the adapter implementation. The main purpose of the `Adapter` itself is to provide the items. In the `FastAdapter` for example the adapter is completely independent of any UI. and will only handle abstract elements.

It's the `View`s job to define how an item will look like and behave. As such this is completely up to the developer, and all flexibility is given.

For showcase purposes such a case was implemented in the sample app of the `FastAdapter`.

You will need to attach an `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to the `RecyclerView` which will handle the swipe action of the user.

With the provided util classes this is done like this:

```
touchCallback = new SimpleSwipeDragCallback(
        this,
        this,
        leaveBehindDrawableLeft,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT,
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.md_red_900)
)
.withBackgroundSwipeRight(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.md_blue_900))
.withLeaveBehindSwipeRight(leaveBehindDrawableRight);

touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(touchCallback); // Create ItemTouchHelper and pass with parameter the SimpleDragCallback
touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView); // Attach ItemTouchHelper to RecyclerView
```

You can find the full sample source code here:
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/SwipeListActivity.java#L120

Comment: Your support is greatly appreciated.